# Why does Google Chrome show the SSRS Report Controller Zoomed Out

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Quick question, I've developed an SSRS solution that is used via a site that offers a lot of Graphs. When in IE the Report Controller works 100% fine, however, when in Google Chrome the SSRS report controller resizes and almost zooms out by 50% or more. How can I force the controller to view in it's original state as IE and Firefox don't have this issue.

I'm sure it is a browser setting, but if not, would I need to resolve this through the website code where we are using C#.NET in Visual Studio .NET 2010 or is there a specific patch or update that the browser requires?

Thanks ahead to anyone who can assist me!!

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of research I've come up only with incompatibility issues between the Microsoft Report Viewer Control and the way that Chrome handles it.

Basically, Chrome cannot handle this control so I've had to inform clients that Firefox and IE are the best options that work consistently.

A pity, as I really wanted to crack it but if anyone does eventually get around this issue the please inform the Forum as this would be of use for every ASP.NET and SSRS Developer